# Can't change value on update with JOIN

Tags: mysql

this is my query:

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a
                    LEFT JOIN ".$SupportUserTable." b
                        ON b.id=a.operator_id
                    SET 
                        a.title=? , 
                        a.priority=?, 
                        b.solved_tickets= CASE WHEN (a.ticket_status='0' AND b.solved_tickets>=1) THEN (b.solved_tickets-1) ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
                        b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN (a.ticket_status='1' AND b.assigned_tickets >=1) THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,
                        a.ticket_status=?, 
                        a.operator_id='0'
                    WHERE a.enc_id=?";
```

I can change all the fields inside `a`, but not the ones inside the table `b` and I don't understand why. I have also checked that `b.id` is equal to `a.operator_id`
 These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_list_tickets` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`enc_id`            CHAR(87),
`ref_id`            VARCHAR(18),
`department_id`     BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`operator_id`       BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`user_id`           BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`title`             VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
`priority`          INT(2)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`website`           VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
`contype`           ENUM('0','1','2','3','4','5')   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`ftp_user`          VARCHAR(60)                 NOT NULL,
`ftp_password`      VARCHAR(60)                 NOT NULL,
`created_time`      DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
`last_reply`        DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
`ticket_status`     ENUM('0','1','2','3')       NOT NULL    DEFAULT '2',
`operator_rate`     DECIMAL(4,2)                UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`user_id`,`title`),
INDEX (`enc_id`,`department_id`,`operator_id`,`user_id`,`ticket_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_users` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`mail`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`password`          VARCHAR(200)                    NOT NULL,
`reg_key`           VARCHAR(260)                    ,
`tmp_password`      VARCHAR(87)                     ,
`ip_address`        VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`status`            ENUM('0','1','2','3','4')       NOT NULL    DEFAULT '3',
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')                   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`mail_alert`        ENUM('no','yes')                NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'yes',
`assigned_tickets`  INT(5)          UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`solved_tickets`    BIGINT(11)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`number_rating`     BIGINT(6)       UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`rating`            DECIMAL(4,2)    UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`mail`),
INDEX (`name`,`mail`,`status`,`holiday`,`assigned_tickets`,`solved_tickets`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55;
```

And these are the users row:

```
(55, 'Admin', mail', 'code', 'code', NULL, '127.0.0.1', '2', '0', 'yes', 0, 0, 1, 4.00),
(62, 'Mario', 'mail', 'code', 'code', NULL, '87.8.28.216', '1', '0', 'yes', 2, 0, 0, 0.00);
```

And this is the ticket row:

```
(60, 'enc_id', 'wwZs1amB', 9, 62, 55, 'Bell', 1, '', '0', '', '', '2013-08-10 12:30:48', '2013-08-10 12:30:48', '1', NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL does not update a single row more than once in an `update` statement.  So, you are not "accumulating" the updates, as you think the query should be.

Also, in one case, the value in `B` is NULL, so thing will be updated.

Here are two alternative approaches:

- Do the updates in two separate statements
- Use triggers to keep the values in `b` consistent with `a`.

Comment: Probably I haven't uderstood, why this query work:
`UPDATE ".$SupportUserTable." a
     INNER JOIN ".$SupportTicketsTable." b 
      ON b.operator_id=a.id
     SET a.rating=ROUND(((a.number_rating * a.rating - (CASE WHEN b.operator_rate>0 THEN b.operator_rate ELSE 0 END) + ?)/(CASE WHEN a.number_rating=0 THEN 1 ELSE a.number_rating+1 END)),2),
      a.number_rating=CASE WHEN b.operator_rate>0 THEN a.number_rating ELSE a.number_rating+1 END,
      b.operator_rate=? 
     WHERE  b.enc_id=?;` What's the difference?

Comment: @Dheed . . . It might be a coincidence.  The order of the updates on table `b` is not determined.  Sometimes it might do it in the right order, sometimes in the wrong order.